# Select other languages for speech recognition

Tags: android, speech-recognition, android-spinner

I use this code to modify different languages for speech recognition, as you see I use a Spinner to select other languages.

```
public static String country;
```

speech recognition code:

```
String name = country;
                Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);


intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                        RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, name);
```

Setting the languages into my Spinner:

```
public String LanguageSelection() {
        language_select_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
               // final String country;
                switch (position){
                    case 0:
                        country="en"; // english
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        country="it"; // itally
                        break;
                }
            }
```

But this does not work in Italy.
It just recognizes English.

How can I solve it?

Comment: What does `it doesn't work in Italy` mean? It works (or doesn't) independently of where you are.

Comment: Quite obviously, you need to have all the language voices you want to use installed on your device. And set the locale accordingly, when you select one through your Spinner selection. Both tasks can be accomplished programmatically.

Comment: you mean that for using each language, that language must be installed on device? but i want to do it generally.

Comment: Of course the language has to be installed on the device. Or it won't work at all. But you can dowload it programmatically, if it's missing on the current device.

Answer (score 0):

To choose a language, you need to add it in your intent, as you did. Just create an Array with the different `Locale.YourLanguage`

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.JAPANESE);
```

But, it will not work if you don't have your language package enabled in your phone. So, the best thing you can do is redirect your user to his phone input options with an intent to `ACTION_INPUT_METHOD_SETTINGS`

Comment: you mean that `ACTION_INPUT_METHOD_SETTINGS` will check if language does not install,it goes to SETTING for install it?

Comment: generally, is there any way exist to recognize voice?(without using google servers)?

Comment: ACTION_INPUT_METHOD_SETTINGS will open the settings menu, and the user must to install the packages. You can check the installed packages using this way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17803487/detect-installed-languages-for-offline-recognition

Comment: You have some libraries which can give you the same function, as Sphinx. But to be honest, the quality is not very good. http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/